# Trying to center 2 responsive tables on center of page

Tags: css

For some reason these 2 tables won't center, I tried the bootstrap container class, tried margin 0 auto. But they won't center smack in the middle, any idea?

I want both tables centered and displayed horizontally in the middle side by side.

It's on codepen over here:
[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/Satearn/pen/ybvXLR)
http://codepen.io/Satearn/pen/ybvXLR

```
  .z
 {position :absolute ;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
  transform :translate(-50%,-50%) ;}
```

Comment: You are using bootstrap right?

Answer (score 1):

To centre align them just remove width: 100%; from your following CSS code.

```
.table-fill {
    background: white;
    border-radius:3px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 320px;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding:5px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    animation: float 5s infinite;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? I used Bootstrap. And I reduced the data inside the table for simplicity

```css
html {
  background-color: #3e94ec;
}


/*** Table Styles **/

.table-fill {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  color: #D5DDE5;
  background: #1b1e24;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #9ea7af;
  border-right: 1px solid #343a45;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-right: none;
}

tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  border-bottom-: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  color: #666B85;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);
}

tr:hover td {
  background: #4E5066;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #22262e;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #22262e;
}

tr:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #EBEBEB;
}

tr:nth-child(odd):hover td {
  background: #4E5066;
}

tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

td {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-right: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}

th.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

th.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

th.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

td.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

td.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

td.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.middlepage {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#outer-cont {
  text-align: center;
}

#target-element-to-center {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table-fill col-xs-6" id="a">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center" colspan="2">Month</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="table-hover">
        <tr>
          <td class="text-left">January</td>
          <td class="text-left">$ 50,000.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table-fill col-xs-6" id="a">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center" colspan="2">Strategies</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="table-hover">
        <tr>
          <td class="text-left">January</td>
          <td class="text-left">$ 50,000.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```